# Standard properties of air

Tags: standards

Where can I find (cite-able sources) properties (such as specific heat at constant volume, thermal conductivity, viscosity etc...) of air at different temperatures (Range of 200K to 2000 K)?

Comment: This looks like a [resource-hunting question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/1832). Such questions are prone to becoming out-dated, and are therefore considered off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cengel's Book: Yunus A. Cengel;John M. Cimbala;Robert H. Turner, Fundamentals of Thermal-Fluid Sciences. 4th. McGraw-Hill, 2012

Here is an extract of the property tables: http://www.kostic.niu.edu/350/_350-posted/350Chengel7th/Appendix1Udated.pdf (for air, see A-2, A-16 and A-17)

There is also: Yunus Cengel and Afshin Ghajar, Heat and Mass Transfer, Fundamentals and Applications, 4th McGraw-Hill, 2011 (for air, see A-15)

They have all the properties of air at 1 atm ($\rho , C_p, k, \alpha , \mu , \nu, Pr$) from -150 $^{\circ}$C to 2000 $^{\circ}$C. See [here](https://www.scribd.com/doc/30589475/Heat-Transfer-Appendix-tables).

Comment: @Wasabi, I don't know if I am allowed to answer to this, since it is off-topic, but I was trying to help. I can delete it, if you think it is irrelevant.

Comment: there's nothing wrong w/ providing an answer, even to a closed question (so long as the answer is useful and so on).